# NVariationalBound

Tags: differential-equations, variational-calculus

I am trying to use the `NVariationalBound` to find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions.

[`NVariationalBound`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/VariationalMethods/ref/NVariationalBound.html) documentation example gives an error as follows:

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]

eqn = y'''[x] + 7  y''[x] + Pi  y'[x] == λ y[x]; 

sol = NVariationalBound[
       {y[x] eqn[[1]], y[x]^2}, y[x], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
       E^(c x), {c, 1}
      ]
```

> During evaluation of In[4]:= FindMinimum::nrnum: The function value
>   Undefined is not a real number at {c} = {1.}. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[4]:= FindMinimum::nrnum: The function value
>   Undefined is not a real number at {c} = {1.}. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[4]:= FindMinimum::nrnum: The function value
>   Undefined is not a real number at {c} = {1.}. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[4]:= General::stop: Further output of
>   FindMinimum::nrnum will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
>
> Out[4]= FindMinimum[ConditionalExpression[-c (-c^2-7
>   c-[Pi]),Re(c)<0],{c,1}]

Can anyone please help me sort it out or else redirect to some other solved problem to understand the syntax?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2):

Change the starting value for `c` from `1` to `-1`.

```
sol = NVariationalBound[{y[x] eqn[[1]], y[x]^2}, y[x], {x, 0, Infinity}, E^(c x), {c, -1}]
(* {-0.364689, {c -> -0.236372}} *)
```

The unevaluated `FindMinimum` result gives a clue:

```
FindMinimum[ConditionalExpression[-c (-7 c - c^2 - π), Re[c] < 0], {c, 1}]
```

It contains an expression which is valid only for `c > 0`, but the starting `c` value is greater than `0`.  `ConditionalExpression` evaluates to `Undefined` when the condition isn't satisfied.